# Is there a way to test functions in testserver in shiny application

Tags: r, shiny

I have a package built so that I am able to test functions using test that. I have 2 scenarios where I test function. One scenario works fine (Sce. A) and other (Sce. B) does not work

Sce.B

```
## app.R (location : D:/Windows/Analytics/R Programming/GitHub/App/pacakge1)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("x", "X", value = 5),
  textOutput("txt"),
  actionButton("button", "Submit")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  server_1(input, output, session , y1)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

```
## file. R (Location : D:/Windows/Analytics/R Programming/GitHub/App/pacakge1/R
server_1 <- function(input, output, session , y1){
  y1 <- reactiveValues(a = 0)
  function1 <- function(){
    y1$a = 2 * input$x
  }

  observeEvent(input$button,{
    function1()
  })

  output$txt <- renderText({
    y1$a
  })

}
```

```
## test server (location : D:/Windows/Analytics/R Programming/GitHub/App/pacakge1/tests/testthat)

library(testthat)
library(shinytest)
library(shiny)

testServer(expr = {
  # y1 <- session$getReturned()
  session$setInputs(x = 7)
  function1()
  expect_equal(y1$a, 14)
})
```

When I test above above scenario (Sce. B). It does not work well. So I need to test if y1$a returns 14 or not
But scenario A below works well since I am not writing server function outside

Sce.A

```
##app.R (Same location as above)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("x", "X", value = 5),
  textOutput("txt"),
  actionButton("button", "Submit")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  y1 <- reactiveValues(a = 0)
  function1 <- function(){
    y1$a = 2 * input$x
  }

  observeEvent(input$button,{
    function1()
  })

  output$txt <- renderText({
    y1$a
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

```
##test server (same location as above)
library(testthat)
library(shinytest)
library(shiny)

testServer(expr = {
  # y1 <- session$getReturned()
  session$setInputs(x = 7)
  function1()
  expect_equal(y1$a, 14)
})
```

Above test passes and allworks well..

But Scenario B is not working.

So the question is here, can we not test functions from other files?

Comment: can anyone help me here please?